# How to setup 32 bit system on Window Azure

Tags: azure

I am playing with window azure SDK and would like to set up my instance as 32 bit system, there are so many option available in "configure OS", so anyone know that by which combination I can set up 32 bit system on Window Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: currently Azure is only configured with 64-bit versions of Windows Server. I would expect this will not change.

If you need a 32-bit operating system you may be better looking for alternative ways to host your application.

Comment: can you please suggest me some way to do that as per you said : "If you need a 32-bit operating system you may be better looking for alternative ways to host your application."

Comment: There's plenty: Amazon Web Services, for instance, have 32-bit AMIs available -- see here: http://aws.amazon.com/amis/Microsoft-Windows What you lose over Azure, however, is the automatic management, transparent failover and easy deployment that Azure gives you.

Comment: Thanks , but i need to required it in Azure only , anyway thanks for you help again.

Comment: Jeremy's answer is right. Why do you need a 32-bit OS? You can run 32-bit apps on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: @smarx Thanks for your answer but please look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834541/getting-peformace-counter-related-error-on-window-azure

Comment: I don't understand how the two are related.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft does support 32 bits OS in Azure, just as long as you upload the image yourself and provides no support for it. Which makes sense. Details on the page [Support for 32-bit operating systems in Azure virtual machines](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4021388/support-for-32-bit-operating-systems-in-azure-virtual-machines):

> Microsoft Azure now allows users to bring in their 32-bit Windows Operating systems over to Azure